# File reading and writing in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    ofstream fout("student",ios::out); 
    char name[30],ch; 
    float marks=0.0; 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    { 
        cout<<"Stud"<<(i+1)<<":\tName"; 
        cin.get(name,30); 
        cout<<"\tMarks"; 
        cin>>marks; 
        cin.get(ch); 
        fout<<name<<'\n'<<marks<<'\n'; 

    } 
    fout.close(); 
    ifstream fin("student",ios::in); 
    fin.seekg(0); 
    cout<<"\n"; 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    { 
        fin.get(name,30); 
        fin.get(ch); 
        fin>>marks; 
        fin.get(ch); 
        cout<<name<<marks; 
    } 
    fin.close(); 
}
```

Now, there are two things I don't understand..why do you need cin.get(ch) while writing to the file(My textbook says to clear the input buffer). How does it help in doing so? I don't have much knowledge about the clearing of a buffer and How does it affect the following iterations?

Further, what if I don't separate the name and marks while writing to the file with a '\n'? 
And, while reading I read it like

```
fin>>get(name,30); 
fin>>marks;
```

Upon running the program I noticed that only the first iteration's values are being repeated 5 times. 
Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the following two lines

```
 cin >> marks; 
 cin.get(ch);
```

In the condition when `marks` is a `char`.
Because input from `cin` with `>>operator` requires pressing Enter from user, code of Enter-key (`'\n'`) will be also in the input buffer.

If you do not remove this `'\n'` from input buffer, at the next iteration of your loop `cin.get(name,30);` will read this single character to `name`.

It was an example for cases when `marks` is a `char`.

In case of incorrect input, e.g. user inputs

```
  4vv6s5
```

as a mark (and `marks` variable is of `float` type) `4` will be taken to `marks`, and `"vv6s5"` to `name` of next student.

So a better way for cleaning input buffer after input can be as follows:

```cpp
cin >> marks; 
do{
    cin.get(ch); 
} while(ch != '\n');
```